# How do I disable the screen going blank for the login screen in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: login-screen, 22.04

How do I prevent the screen from going blank after a period of inactivity for the **login screen** in 22.04?

I tried setting `sleep-inactive-ac-timeout=0` and `sleep-inactive-ac-type='nothing'` in `/etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults` and rebooting, but this doesn't seem to have done anything.

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 on a Dell Latitude 7280 laptop.

I need to do this because after the screen is blank for a period of time, it won't turn back on and I have to cycle power. I'm hoping that preventing the screen from going blank will be an easier fix than figuring out that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Settings > Privacy > Screen > Blank Screen Display > Never

Answer (score -1):

How about pressing the power icon -> select Settings -> choose the Screen tab, you should see the "Blank Screen Delay", you can set it to "Never".
Hope it helps.

Comment: That works, but just when a user is logged in. It doesn't apply to the login screen itself.

Answer (score -1):

First, install the systemd-container package if not installed in your system.

```
sudo apt install systemd-container
```

then you can configure the settings via the command line like below.

```
sudo machinectl shell gdm@ /bin/bash
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 0
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing'
exit
```

Comment: I tried that, rebooted, and the login screen still goes blank.

Comment: Hi, can you change ac-timeout to something big like 120, are you on battery or ac? try to set both to 120

Comment: I am on AC. I executed...
`sudo machinectl shell gdm@ /bin/bash`
`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 120`
`exit`
... and rebooted. The login screen still went blank after 5 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the power option. I had a problem like yours. Even if I turn off the dim screen, after 30 seconds the screen continues to go . I changed my power mode from power saving to balanced and it worked

Answer (score -1):

It may be a simple screensaver. Just go to settings and disable screensaver. It worked for me.